# Table View Controller each row connected to different view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to develop a Table View Controller,where rows are connected to multiple `View Controllers` (TextField,TextView,TableView,DatePicker,ImageView etc.).

So if I click on any row,it should open the `Intermediate View` and place the appropriate controller in a common place where rest of the thing will be same for all controller.Suppose I clicked on a row where the index is mapped to TableView.When It will open the Intermediate Controller, It should placed the tableview in the common container,this table view should come from a single TableView controller for all other Tableview.

I am new in ios and not able to design this.

What is the best way to design this? How do I implement this?

[image: Root Table View]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: This is too broad: Is your question about how to capture the index of the cell selected or how to parse to the appropriate VC or how to segue?

Comment: updated my question.please have a look.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest that don't create cell in Storyboard and connect it. Instead leave empty table in storyboard and create cell using code. You can create custom cell by subclassing `UITableViewCell`.

In storyboard you just link table view with all view controller using segue and give it proper *identifier name*.

[image]

Now implement all delegates methods of `UITableView`. Override `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method and on row selection perform segue for specific row.

**Example:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"BasicCoreDataSegue" sender:self];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Here in above case if you select first row it will push view controller which is connect with `BasicCoreDataSegue` segue in Storyboard, you can compare it with image.

Using similar way create other segues and call them in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method in different switch case.

Also If you want to pass any values to push controller, override below method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"BasicCoreDataSegue"]) {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        TextViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.textView.text = "Hello";
    }
}
```

### Edit:

Above code works for common controller. Now you don't need to create more segues also in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method set Intermediate controller segue.

Use `[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]` method to get selected row in `prepareForSegue` method.

**For Example:**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"BasicCoreDataSegue" sender:self];
}
```

Now when `prepareForSegue` is called then set integer value for Intermediate controller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].

        // You can get selected row using below line
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"BasicCoreDataSegue"]) {
            // Get reference to the destination view controller
            IntermediateController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
            vc.selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
        }
    }
```

In above code `selectedIndex` is a integer variable which is used to track that which row is selected.

Now in Intermediate controller in `-viewDidLoad()` use switch case to get controller object which you want from row selection and add its view as a subview in Intermediate Controller.

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                         bundle: nil];

TextViewController *controller = (TextViewController*)[storyBoard 
                    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"TextViewControllerId"];

[self.topView addSubview:controller.view];
```

Comment: everything is clear. Now if I want to load the controller(i.e -Tableview) from a TableViewController,where that table view is generated in the viewDidLoad(). How to add the tableview as a subview in this topView?

Comment: For that you can directly create `UITableView` object in `-viewDidLoad()` method. And add as a subview, "OR" you can create this topView as a different class (manage table view and delegates in that class) and just create object of this subclass in `-viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: I have done like that,for all other field its working fine. but for tableview its fails with reason [UIImage numberOfSectionInTableView].I am not able to set the datasource and delegate.

Comment: You need to set delegate and datasource of tableView right after creating object. Like `[self.tableView setDelegate:self]; [self.tableView setDatasource:self];` And extend view controller interface with `UITableViewDelegate` & `UITableViewDatasource`. Like `@interface IntermediateController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>`