# show a common progress bar in multiple(more than 2) view controllers

Tags: swift

I have about 7 to 8 view controllers for registration process and I need to show one common progress bar. I tried container view but its not going properly. Is there any another way to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use view controller containment concept.

Also for more better visibility on same you can refer [Same UIProgressView Over Multiple View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023771/same-uiprogressview-over-multiple-view-controllers)

Comment: I tried same, almost a year back and it worked for me.